# Type mapping and collapsing `number | (str: string) => void` to `number | string`

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a class with a high degree of flexibility in a "schema" you can provide:

```
// example schema
type Schema = {
  numReceiver: (num: number) => void;
  num: number;
  stringReceiver: (str: string) => void;
  string: string;
};
```

I'm trying to create a higher level type (`SchemaParameters`) that can extract the "parameters" of the schema. At first, I only needed to extract the following types:

```
Schema<'num'> => [number]
Schema<'stringReceiver'> => [string]
Schema<'string'> => [string]
```

I previously had:

```
export type SchemaParameters<T> = [T] extends [(...args: infer U) => any]
  ? U
  : [T] extends [void]
  ? []
  : [T];
```

This works when I do:

```
// expected behavior, works
const fromConstant: SchemaParameters<Schema['string']> = ['lorem ipsum'];
const fromFunction: SchemaParameters<Schema['stringReceiver']> = ['lorem ipsum 2'];
```

However, I now have the need to do something like:

```
const value: SchemaParameters<Schema['num' | 'stringReceiver']> = ['lorem ipsum'];
```

where `SchemaParameters<Schema['num' | 'stringReceiver']>` would resolve to `number | string`. However, this is getting reduced to:

```
SchemaParameters<Schema['num' | 'stringReciever']>

SchemaParameters<number | (str: string) => void>

[number | (str: string) => void] extends [(...args: infer U) => any] ? U : [T] extends [void] : [] : [T]

[number | (str: string) => void] extends [void] ? [] : [T]

[number | (str: string) => void]
```

Normally, in `SchemaParameters`, if `T = (str: string) => void`, that ternary results in the first side being chosen (`U`). However, when `T = number | (str: string) => void`, this ternary just results in the more ordinary path (the value themselves).

In this case, that means `SchemaParameters<Schema['num' | 'stringReciever']>` evaluates to `number | (str: string) => void`.

Similarly although not identically, `SchemaParameters<Schema['numReceiver' | 'stringReceiver']>` results in `[number & string]` which means `[never]`. I guess in this case it *is* `infer`ring `U`, but `U` is `number & string`. I think I'd like to move away from using `infer` like this, but I'm really not sure how.

How can I rewrite `SchemaParameters` to work with sum types here? I'm also open-minded to using variadic tuples, but I can't figure out how to use them to accomplish this.

[TypeScript playground with most of this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAygYwBZQLYEMYF4YG9gwwB2ArqgEpQJQCWAblAE4BcMAFKaq5wEZMCU2AHww6AexoATANwFiZbmT6NZhAM4hGNIgHNK1ek1ZsNLGKe07BWEeKmrzmy6wu7ZAX1nAA9ACpgiCgYADwA5JyhIjYwANq8TAC6Acho6GGuelS0DIyRwrEZSYGp6U66edExhcC+3sD1UAAeEGKMIDDg0PApGAAK6IzoqFAgTGrBACpRsRMJME2jRJJqsWwAdBsDOmqs2gBmTDAAqtYi6ERgSYQA-MdyrDGz842Ly7F2klcwtzFfD7NebzeZ7QBCjSQwPhIdB0GitAA0MAA7q0ANZqYAIMREDQwPaMMSoADC2I05xArGKfQGQxGY2CVPQMVCGVCCWmzIANq00DAaBA1GQ2bIsTj2vjCQAxEhEMFwoiUnrofqDYajRjjRnMjL6bJMNkc0Lcxi8-mC1AwABMwsxpPanEVQWVNLV9K14SF7OwsQArAkvKLcRLUABRGggFCMaWykDyx2pFW09WapXMzi6wy5GAAHxgLLKmQMOQN3t+gOBAAEQGoALRNUEgOuMAmMW1i0ToTkkKCSgmoI5EOPdJ2J10ahmpj2oUI5vM6rKZks4Lk8i1mz3SIA)

Comment: I believe you just have to include distribution over union types. https://tsplay.dev/N7gbGN If I correctly understood what you want

Comment: @aleksxor I think your solution 100% works, but I have no idea why. How does adding an extra `extends unknown` (which pretty much always resolves, right?) make the higher order type "include distribution over union types"? Thank you so much either way, and you should definitely write this as an answer so I can mark it as correct!

Comment: Yes it matches unknown each time and thus distributes the type calculation by it's constituents. I'll try to describe it in details in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achive what you want you just have to include distribution over union types. While you provide `[T] extends [<smth>]` into conditional type the union type `T` doesn't get distributed. So the most simple way is just provide [naked types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```ts
type SchemaParameters<T> = T extends (...args: infer U) => any
    ? U
    : [T] extends [void]
        ? []
        : [T]
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Nrv2oN)

---

### Update

If you need to account for `any` type and present the result type as `[any]` you should specialcase it:

```ts
type SchemaParameters<T> = unknown extends T ? [T] :
    T extends (...args: infer U) => any
        ? U
        : [T] extends [void]
            ? []
            : [T]
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mMRydW)

Otherwise in the version with naked types it gets distributed into both branches of the conditional type and you'll get `unknown[]` (inferred as arguments of unknown function) from the first branch and `[]` since `[any] extends [void]` from the second branch unified into `unknown[] | []`.

In the version from the comments it'll get shortcircuited into the first branch and you'll get only `unknown[]` as inferrence of the function arguments.

Comment: This works for the test cases I've set up, but it doesn't seem to work for `any`. I would hope this would result in `[any]` yet it seems to result in `unknown | unknown[]`. Do you know how I might fix this problem?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I was just trying to reproduce the problem as succinctly as I could (returning `any` instead of `[any]`) when you edited. :) Thank you!